# Matlab Simulation and distributions

Tags: matlab

I need to simulate 100 outcomes from the Exp(5) distribution using the inverse transform method. Calculate the sample mean (average of these outcomes).

For this part I have done the inverse transform part and got the function to be:

```
x = - log(u) / λ
```

So, this is what I have for my code so far:

```
lambda = 5;
n = 100;
U = rand(1, n);
X = -log(U)/lambda;
mean(X)
```

However, I'm not sure if this is correct for the first part of this question where it asks to calculate the sample mean.

However, the question also asks to re-peat this experiment 1000 times, and then plot the empirical cdf of the 1000 sample means. Also show the expected average of these outcomes i.e. the true mean. However, I don't know how to do that. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the mean of 100 samples might differ a bit in between different runs. Even more so, it kind of makes sense that the mean of 100 samples isn't exactly the expected value of your exponential distribution. Your teacher wants you to analyse this behaviour (the analytical equivalent of which has been asked on mathoverflow: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155296/distribution-of-the-sample-mean-of-a-exponential )

For a start, you might want create an array of 1x1000, and store the results of 1000 of those experiments in there. Then compute the `ecdf` (a buildin matlab function), and plot the result.

Comment: For the "empirical cdf" as the OP mentioned, it would be [`ecdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ecdf.html) – unless the idea is to write one's own version of this.

Comment: @horchler You're right. Don't know how i confused them, but it's fixed now.